# Calculation of chern class

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

For Chern class, we have this formula $$c(E\oplus F)=c(E)c(F),$$ where $E$ and $F$ are complex vector bundle over a manifold $M$.
$c(E)=1+c_1(E)+\cdots$ is the total chern class of $E$.
Do we have some similar formula for $\mathrm{Sym}^n(E)$ and $\Lambda^n(E)$ which are symmetric power and exterior power respectively?

EDIT:Following Qiaochu Yuan's idea, I try to use splitting principle.
I am trying do the case $E=L_1\oplus L_2\oplus \cdots \oplus L_n$ where $L_i$ are line bundle. Let $Q=\mathrm{Sym}^2(E)$.

But in general if we have a short exact sequence of algebraic vector bundle say 
$$0\rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C\rightarrow 0,$$ it is possible that this sequence doesn't split. Do we still have $c(B)=c(A)c(C)$?

Comment: Yes, but they're more complicated. Use the splitting principle.

Comment: Regarding your edit, Chern classes make sense in the purely topological setting of topological vector bundles, and in that setting all short exact sequences of vector bundles split. As far as I know this doesn't help you apply the splitting principle though.

Comment: A lot of this should be in Chapter 3 of Fulton's book. I'm not suggesting reading it from beginning to end, but there ought to be statements you can rely on there.

Comment: I will take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_i$ be the chern roots of the rank-$n$ vector bundle $E$, i.e. the classes $x_i\in H^2(M)$ such that the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $x_i$ equal the chern classes of $E$. Or
$$
c(E)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)
$$

Then

$$
c(\Lambda E)=\prod_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\ldots<x_k\leq n}(1+x_{i_1}+\ldots +x_{i_k}),
$$

and
$$
c({\rm Sym} (E))=\prod_{1\leq i_1\leq i_2\leq\ldots<x_k\leq n}(1+x_{i_1}+\ldots +x_{i_k}).
$$

It will take some work to translate this back to expressions involving only the chern classes of $E$ (but is always possible)